# JS code wont run on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am currently facing issue with JS and IE compatibility.

I applied a new function in my webap in its JS part its working fine in IE11,Firefox and chrome but when the user access the site using IE9 some code wont work.

is there a way to fix  this ?
I am always redirected to a blank page
Ive also tried using .replace and .assign and even

```
var url = 'link'
$(location).attr('href', url);
```

Ive already place a tag in my htm but still not working:

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE9">
```

JS

```
$scope.isVerify = function ()
    {                

        if (UserLevel == '0010')
        {

            window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject='' + '&body='';
            return false;


        }   
        else {
            $window.location.href = $scope.details.(returntoprevpage)

        }

    };
```

Comment: You haven't included the JavaScript that's failing, any hint of errors you might see in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), the surrounding HTML, or anything else that might tell us what's failing. There's no way for anyone to guess what is/isn't happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per checking the issue is not on the windows.location it appears that the issue we on the email body which pass the allowable length on IE9

I am able to create a work around using iframe